# breakpoints in cloud9IDE

Tags: javascript, node.js, cloud9-ide

I am using cloud9 for a nodejs project. If I place a breakpoint in `server.js` it triggers just fine, however if I place a breakpoint in any other module it never triggers. I have placed a `console.log` statement in my other module to confirm it is running. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that a breakpoint created by clicking in the margin will not follow a callback function as it is passed around. The solution is to insert `debugger;` directly at the point in which a breakpoint is desired.